# Composing data structures during reduce/fold

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

I'm working on a Natural Language Processing project (and learning Elixir), and can't figure out the idiomatic way to transform my data.

In order not to bore you with inane domain details, let's transpose the problem to parsing addresses.

Given a list of string tokens, use relevant tokens to compose a data structure in-place while leaving the others where they are:

```
# input
["in", "France:",  "22", "Rue", "du", "Débarcadère", ",", "75017", "Paris", ",", "France", "where", "they", "are"]
MyModule.process(tokens)

# output
["in", "France:",  %Address{
  street: "Rue du Débarcadère",
  street_number: 22,
  zip: 75017,
  city: "Paris",
  country: "France"
}, "where", "they", "are"]

# input
["in", "the", "USA:", "125", "Maiden", "Lane", ",", "11th", "Floor",
"New", "York", ",", "NY", "10038", "USA", "where", "they", "are"]

# output
["in", "the", "USA:",  %Address{
  street: "Maiden Lane",
  street_number: 125,
  floor: 11,
  zip: 10038,
  city: "New York",
  state: "NY",
  country: "USA"
}, "where", "they", "are"]
```

Turning a sequence of tokens into an `Address` struct will require some country-specific logic (different ways of formatting addresses, etc.), which we'll assume is available. Further, let's assume that I'm able to switch to the appropriate parsing logic (i.e. which country the address is in) by looking at the tokens (e.g. the token ending with ":").

Once again, what I'm trying to achieve:

1. iterate over tokens until one triggers a special case (a country name followed by ":")
2. consume all relevant tokens (process tokens from "22" to "France" in first example)
3. replace them with a struct (an `%Address{}`)
4. continue iterating on the first unprocessed token ("where")

Some form of `reduce` would seem appropriate, but `reduce` itself wouldn't continue iterating where I want it to, and `reduce_while` doesn't seem to be the ticket either...

And it shouldn't make a difference, but I'd like to be able to apply the same logic/process at a higher level and compose higher-level data structures, e.g.:

```
# input
["the", "Mirabeau", "restaurant", "at", %Address{...}, "where", "he", "cooked"]

# output
["the", %Place{
  name: "Mirabeau",
  type: :restaurant,
  location: %Address{...}
}, "where", "he", "cooked"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Stream.unfold/2` for this. Pass all the token as the initial accumulator, then from the function, return a tuple of a term and the new accumulator. In the case of a country name followed by `:`, you can consume as many further tokens as you want and return the remaining ones. For others, you can simply return the head and continue with the tail.

Here's a tiny example which does this:

```
["in", "France:",  "22", "Rue", "du", "Débarcadère", ",", "75017",
 "Paris", ",", "France", "where", "they", "are", "in", "the", "USA:", "125",
 "Maiden", "Lane", ",", "11th", "Floor", "New", "York", ",", "NY", "10038",
 "USA", "where", "they", "are"]
|> Stream.unfold(fn
  [] -> nil
  [h | t] ->
    if String.ends_with?(h, ":") do
      {street, t} = Enum.split_while(t, &(&1 != ","))
      ["," | t] = t
      {rest, t} = Enum.split_while(t, &(&1 <> ":" != h))
      [country | t] = t
      {%{street: street, rest: rest, country: country}, t}
    else
      {h, t}
    end
end)
|> Enum.to_list
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
["in",
 %{country: "France", rest: ["75017", "Paris", ","],
   street: ["22", "Rue", "du", "Débarcadère"]}, "where", "they", "are", "in",
 "the",
 %{country: "USA", rest: ["11th", "Floor", "New", "York", ",", "NY", "10038"],
   street: ["125", "Maiden", "Lane"]}, "where", "they", "are"]
```